# How to get the window back with code after Reachability (double-tap home) triggered on iPhone 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

Double-tap on iPhone 6's home button will shift the window down to let user can reach the top of the window. Tap into a UITextField(show **inputView**) or show **UIActionSheet** can let the window get back.

So is there a line of code can get the window back **without showing an extra view**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no public way to achieve what you're asking for yet.

Digging a little bit deeper we can find `UIApplication`'s private method called `_deactivateReachability` made exactly for this problem. You can call it this way:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"_deactivateReachability")];
```

But keep in mind that **this solution will probably get your app rejected during the app review** because of the usage of private undocumented API and it's better to wait when Apple will make public API for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Swift Version of Ilya's answer:

```
UIApplication.shared.perform(Selector(("_deactivateReachability")))
```